# How can I fix item positions in my form in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make my own monopoly game in C# with Visual Studio but I have problems with the position of my items.

This is how I want to see the game with all resolutions:

[image: Good]

but when I resize the main window this is what I get:

[image: Bad]

I have put that buttons like monopoly's properties, inside of a panel which is inside of the form with a fixed position adapted to the parent (the window), but the buttons aren't adapted to his parent (the panel) and I want to know how to fix their position to autosize and autoposition themselves.

The panel is fixed in his position by the tool *Dock* set as *fill* but I can't use this tool with the buttons because it has only five different positions for top, right, left, bottom or center and uses all the space.

Comment: You should probably use WPF instead.

Comment: You need to use docks or reposition every element on the resize event. WPF handles this much better though, because it doesn\t use X,Y for positions.

Comment: I think you can use a TableLayoutPanel, create the appropiate rows/columns and then add the table slots on the created cells and set their dock to fill

Comment: use the controls' anchor property

Comment: @Rakitić anchor will not work with such a complex dessign, you can't expand controls percentually with anchors.

Comment: @Gusman I would rather stick to your comment...it seems more appropriate...lest it's always better to use a WPF.

Comment: @Rakitić agreed that for such type of project would be a lot better to use WPF, but I assume the user will not want to rewrite everything he has done (@David, if you didn't wrote still any code, change to WPF)

Comment: @David if it's only the design part you have done yet...it's better you migrate to WPF...things will become much easier.

Comment: @Valentin I need to change the size for the different window resolutions, it is seen well in my resolution 1980x1720 but not in less resolution

Comment: @Gusman I have written another forms' code but I can change it without problem however I have never used WPF before, does it uses the same language?

Comment: The language is the same, the design and controls are different, per example, you will describe your interface with XAML instead of code, the contros aren't winforms cotrols but wpf controls, etc etc. Maybe this is a good moment to learn WPF, for a game is a must, it will use DirectX to accelerate all the rendering so you will be able to do things unthinkable on WinForms, also the controls are a lot more flexible. And it's not this difficult ;)